# Как отследить закрытие пользователем приложения?

Tags: android, xamarin

В моем приложении пользователь запускает таймер. Если этот таймер заканчивается, что-то должно произойти. Но есть такой вариант, что пользователь отключает приложение. Можно ли как-то отследить это и записать в базу данных, что он не дождалась окончания таймера?

Comment: запишите начало таймера а при следующем сеансе проверьте запись окончания и если ее нет выполняйте нужные действия

Comment: Оу, точно) Спасибо

Comment: А можно как-то отследить что пользователь свернул приложение?

Answer (score 2):

Имплементируйте в ваш класс `Application` интерфейс `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` и вы сможете контролировать жизненные циклы всех ваших `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отследить закрытие приложения можно использовать подход SingleActivity. Тогда у Вас будет одна единственная Activity, которая будет жить на протяжении всего приложения. Сворачивание Activity будет эквивалентно сворачиванию приложения и Вы сможете отследить его в методе onDestroy(). 
Подробнее о подходе SingleActivity можно почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/426617/).

Comment: onDestroy() не всегда срабатывает